# root in binary tree always NULL

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

The program should read a txt, store all the words alphabetically and print them in order, with the number of times the word appears on the txt.

The problem seems to be in the Insert method, because it never prints TEST, so it seems the pAux is always NULL for some reason. And because of that, the Print method returns in his first call.

What am I doing wrong?

tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H_
#define TREE_H_

typedef struct Item{
    char* key;
    int no;
} TItem;

typedef struct No{
    TItem item;
    struct No* pLeft;
    struct No* pRight;
} TNo;

void TTree_Insert (TNo**, char[]);
void TTree_Print (TNo*);

#endif
```

tree.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tree.h"

TNo* TNo_Create (char* c){
    TNo* pNo = malloc(sizeof(TNo));
    pNo->item.key = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(c));
    strcpy(pNo->item.key, c);
    pNo->item.no = 1;
    pNo->pLeft = NULL;
    pNo->pRight = NULL;
    return pNo;
}

void TTree_Insert (TNo** pRoot, char word[80]){
    char* c = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word));
    strcpy(c, word);
    TNo** pAux;
    pAux = pRoot;
    while (*pAux != NULL){
        if (strcmp(c, (*pAux)->item.key) < 0) pAux = &((*pAux)->pLeft);
        else if (strcmp(c, (*pAux)->item.key) > 0) pAux = &((*pAux)->pRight);
        else{
            (*pAux)->item.no++;
            return;
        }
    }
    *pAux = TNo_Create(c);
    return;
}

void TTree_Print (TNo *p){
    if (p == NULL) return;
    TTree_Print (p->pLeft);
    printf("%s - %d", p->item.key, p->item.no);
    TTree_Print (p->pRight);
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "tree.h"

int main(){
    TNo* pRoot = NULL;
    FILE* txt = fopen("Loremipsum.txt", "r");
    char aux[80];
    int c, x = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(txt)) != EOF){
        while (!(isalpha((char)c))) c = fgetc(txt);
        while (isalpha((char)c)) {
            if (isupper((char)c)) c = c+32;
            if (islower((char)c)) aux[x++] = (char)c;
            c = fgetc(txt);
        }
        aux[x] = '\0';
        TTree_Insert(&pRoot, aux);
        x = 0;
        aux[0] = '\0';
    }
    TTree_Print(pRoot);
    fclose(txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never change the value of pRoot. TTree_Insert just gets the value of pRoot. You assign the adddess of the new node to pAUx, but that is discarded when the function returns.

Comment: If you're modifying a variable from main you need to pass that variables reference to the function

Comment: You're passing `pRoot` by value.

Answer (score 1):

I did not look through all your code. I will answer only your question. You have to pass pRoot to TTree_Insert by reference. Otherwise you pass its copy to the function and any changes of the copy within the function do not influence the original value.

For example

```
void TTree_Insert ( TNo **pRoot, char word[80] ){
    char* c = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word) + 1 ); // <==
    strcpy( c, word ); // <==
    TNo* pAux;
    pAux = *pRoot;        
    //...
```

And in main you have to call the function like

```
TTree_Insert( &pRoot, aux );
```

Take into account that you have to adjust  all other code of the function. For example

```
void TTree_Insert( TNo **pRoot, const char word[80] )
{
    char* c = malloc( sizeof( char ) * strlen( word ) + 1 );

    strcpy( c, word );

    TNo **pAux = pRoot;

    while ( *pAux != NULL )
    {
        printf("TESTE");
        if ( strcmp(c, ( *pAux )->item.key ) < 0 )
        {
            pAux = &pAux->pLeft;
        }
        else if ( strcmp(c,  ( *pAux )->item.key ) > 0 )
        {
             pAux = &pAux->pRight;
        }
        else
        { 
            ( *pAux )->item.no++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( *pAux == NULL ) *pAux = TNo_Create(c);

    return;
}
```

I hope it will work.:)

Comment: thanks, I adjusted the code to use ** and & and now it's working. the strcpy thing was already fixed, but I forgot to mentiion. Thanks.

Comment: you obviously did some other changes as well because that code doesn't modify `pRoot`.

Comment: yes, as I said, I adjusted the code to use **pRoot and Insert(&pRoot), following the comments in the question.

Comment: yes? that's a no. I said "other". this alone couldn't possibly fix it.

Comment: @ColdLucas You could write    TNo** pAux;
    pAux = pRoot;
    while (*pAux != NULL){ and so on.

Comment: I wrote TNo** pAux; pAux = *pRoot; while (pAux != NULL){  instead. btw, now there's a big memory leak somewhere (the c issue is fixed) because when I try with a txt with 1000 words, the code works. but with 10000 it stops responding. should I reopen the question and edit with the new code?

Comment: that's what I meant by "other changes". BTW that shouldn't even compile.

Comment: note: `( *pAux ) == NULL` - this will always be true. assuming you'll ever reach it because you could also have an infinte loop.

Comment: Vlad, I did almost the same you did, but used return instead of break. But i'm still with the memory problem. can you see where is it going? (the main method works with a dynamic array, so the problem must be in the tree.c method..)

Comment: @ColdLucas It will be better if you will ask a new question with the updated code.

Comment: done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961797/memory-leak-somewhere-in-the-code

Answer (score 0):

`pRoot` is initially `NULL`, and you never change it later.

> so it seems the pAux is always NULL for some reason

Well, that's the reason... why don't you use a debugger or do some printing?